# No images on any scope on my BQ E4.5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a weird problem in that there are no images (pictures) in any scope, including a picture scope. The boxes exist but they are all blank. Other than resetting back to factory settings is there anything else I can do to restore them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1430828 
You should be able to reset the network connection and see them, perhaps toggle flight mode on and off or toggle the WiFi connection.